# What's the best way to structure MongoClient and express: Client inside routes or routes inside client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

What's the best way to use MongoClient in Express? Client inside routes or routes inside client? I've seen some tutorials on both and now i'm confuse which is the right one to follow?

```
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    MongoClient.connect('connection_str',(err,db)=>{
      err? console.log(`Error: ${err}`) :
      db.collection('collection_name',(err,docs)=>{
         err? console.log(`Error: ${err}`) :
         res.json(docs);
      });
    });
});
```

**OR**

```
MongoClient.connect('connection_str',(err,db)=>{
    app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
        db.collection('collection_name',(err,docs)=>{
           err? console.log(`Error: ${err}`) :
           res.json(docs);
        });
    });
});
```

The first one seems secure but will be redundant on different routes while the second is ideal for different routes, i just started learning the mern stack and wanted to just use mongodb's native mongo client instead of mongoose. What's the best approach guys? THANKS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend none of the approach you are currently using. Instead, i would suggest that you create a database connection once, and reuse that connection for all your routes, or you can go ahead with database pool as well.

From official docs :

> A Connection Pool is a cache of database connections maintained by the
>   driver so that connections can be re-used when new connections to the
>   database are required. To reduce the number of connection pools
>   created by your application, we recommend calling **MongoClient.connect
>   once** and reusing the database variable returned by the callback:

This is an example showing how you can create a connection once and reuse the connection:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var db;

// Initialize connection once
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/integration_test", function(err, database) {
  if(err) throw err;

  db = database;

  // Start the application after the database connection is ready
  app.listen(3000);
  console.log("Listening on port 3000");
});

// Reuse database object in request handlers
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    db.collection('collection_name',(err,docs)=>{
        err ? console.log(`Error: ${err}`) :
           res.json(docs);
        });
    });
});
```

For more information, please read [official mongodb-native documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html#mongoclient-connection-pooling)

Comment: Cool! Ravi Shankar Bharti! from now on i will use the method you suggest, thanks a lot man!

Comment: Glad i could help you out man! Please mark it as accepted answer, so that it can help others as well.